# How can I split large CSS files with python?

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x

The problem that I am having comes form the fact that [IE 8 has limits for CSS files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx). In my Flask project, some of my CSS files exceed these limits and they don't render properly.

Does anyone know how I can split CSS files with Python so that I can make my files meet the limits that IE 8 imposes on CSS?

Comment: If you have more than 4000 but not more than 8000 rules, why not just use your text editor to roughly cut the file in half?

Comment: +1 @nkorth, while this will work we have a lot of rules and are actively adding more over time. We also use SASS to make our css file. This is an excellent suggestion which we might use in the short term but I'd be interested in finding a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. It will of course have to be modified to become either a command line tool to run after SASS, or perhaps some sort of filter in your Flask code.

```
css = "the contents of your enormous css file"
rules = re.findall(r'[^\{]+\{[^\}]*\}', css, re.MULTILINE)

print 'Number of rules: ', len(rules)

with open('output1.css', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(rules[:4096]))
if len(rules) > 4096:
    with open('output2.css', 'w') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(rules[4096:]))
```

Comment: I ended up concluding that it would be fastest to just write a script myself (like you did, though I used cssutils). I incorporated this script into the build script for my application so that when I build it, I generate these css files dynamically.